# iReport Designer 5.6.0 style encoding does not work in generated pdf

Tags: encoding, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I have created a report template, with a style:

```
<style name="style1" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
```

The full xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="59f4ec24-a6d9-4c6a-b4a9-735007397fbc">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<style name="style1" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="59" y="82" width="161" height="20" uuid="d9389d6d-d10f-4376-8282-7b1bd931c360"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

The generated pdf somehow does not include the character encoding. What property/iDesigner option or setting should be set? Or encoding should be set separately in every field/text property?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a style to a template can solve this problem.
On the style check the Pdf Embedded checkbox and select the required Pdf Encoding from the selection list.